# Search and filter a list of lists

Tags: arrays, django, python-3.x, list, tuples

thanks for your time, I'm new in Python so I got this list of lists:

```
raw-list = [
[((733, 706), (810, 733)), 'Joe'], 
[((748, 613), (815, 637)), 'Harold'], 
[((748, 614), (815, 638)), 'Harold'], 
[((815, 614), (882, 638)), 'Walter'], 
[((816, 614), (883, 638)), 'Walter'], 
[((883, 613), (950, 637)), 'Parker'], 
[((883, 614), (950, 638)), 'Parker'], 
[((902, 694), (969, 718)), 'Ernesto'], 
[((950, 613), (1017, 637)), 'Max'], 
[((950, 614), (1017, 638)), 'Max']
]
```

I would like to delete all the lists that already have a name that has been mentioned previously to obtain this:

```
filtered_list = [
[((733, 706), (810, 733)), 'Joe'], 
[((748, 613), (815, 637)), 'Harold'], 
[((815, 614), (882, 638)), 'Walter'], 
[((883, 613), (950, 637)), 'Parker'], 
[((902, 694), (969, 718)), 'Ernesto'], 
[((950, 614), (1017, 638)), 'Max']
]
```

How can I achieve that?, Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Harold got first row seen but Max got last row seen.  Why?

Comment: What makes the items filtered special? Right now it's _very_ difficult to guess what exactly you want. Besides that, have you attempted anything? Perhaps you've researched a function? Try looking up `filter()` or maybe come up with an attempt with for-loops and if-statements.

Comment: I guess you need to use `set` instead of `list` as you have used here.